# $k$-cube definition clarrification

Tags: definition, differential-forms

If $c:I^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a singular $k$-cube.

What will $\partial c$ be?

Will it be a singular $(k-1)$-cube or a $(k+1)$-cube or something else?

Definition - A singular $k$-cube on $U$ is a smooth map $c:I^k\rightarrow U$

where $I^k=\{t\in\mathbb{R}^k\mid 0\leq t^i\leq 1\}$ denotes the closed unit $k$-cube in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Comment: $\partial c$ will be a signed sum of singular $(k-1)$-cubes. For an exact definition of the boundary operator, see [page 345 of the book "Topology" by John Gilbert Hocking](https://books.google.de/books?id=7XSKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=topology+singular+cube+boundary+operator&source=bl&ots=VwPR2eLTTT&sig=evf7C9oD-hkvV_DbWoZ8AG0s9n4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=oxWxVKacDIeraff-gcgG&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=topology%20singular%20cube%20boundary%20operator&f=false).

Comment: Another thing: why do you call your cubes singular if they are supposed to be smooth? What's the relation to the tag "differential-forms" on your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes more sense now. The topic is mentioned in "integration of differential forms" in my lecture notes, so for lack of a better tag I used differential-forms.

Comment: @jflipp If you fancy earning a few easy points, post a brief answer and ill give you +1 and correct answer.